# @ConfigurationProperties can be autowired but is not a spring bean

Tags: spring

The following class could be injected by `@Autowired` and also as a constructor parameter in consumer class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "temp")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@Setter
public class TemporaryProperties {

    Boolean changerole = false;

    Boolean roleauth = false;
}
```

But when I use it in thymeleaf:

```
<div th:if="${@temporaryProperties.getRoleauth()}">
```

an error rises:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'temporaryProperties' available.

So now I see @Autowired like a stranger.

Comment: No it cannot be autowired.

Answer (score 0):

Your class *TemporaryProperties* is not spring bean. Add annotation *@Component* to class *TemporaryProperties* to add instance of class *TemporaryProperties* to spring context.

Comment: I know it is not a spring bean, but it can be autowired.

Comment: Yes, Spring can autowire non-managed beans.But as far as I know Thymeleaf can use only spring managed beans in such expressions as ${@temporaryProperties.getRoleauth()}.